# How to attach a textbox to a curve in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following figure is created in a visualization software:
[image]

where I can attach a textbox label to a curve. Is there any way to achieve the same behavior in Python?

To possibly simplify things, the textbox doesn't have to be a particular location on the curve. I just needs to be close to or preferably on the curve.

Comment: There are several ways, e.g. using `plt.text()`. See the demo here: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/fancytextbox_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-text-labels-and-annotations-fancytextbox-demo-py

Comment: @Arne Works! But how do I change the color of the textbox? I tried specifying `facecolor` but that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Hmm seems I can change the color by specifying them in `ec` and `fc`.  Not sure what `facecolor` does

Comment: @lamanon thanks for letting me know that it works! I guess `facecolor` would control the color of a scatterplot-like marker, should you include one.

Comment: Maybe with `clabel` in a `contour` plot [see contour demo with clabels](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contour_demo.html#)